# Decompose a Mesh so that each piece can be watched by a Guard inside the piece

Tags: computational-geometry

The title pretty much explains it but I'm gonna go into more details. 
We have 3D mesh object and we want to decompose it into separate objects so that each one of these objects can be seen completely if we place a point somewhere inside them. The point location will not be random. We just need to make sure that there is a place inside the objects where the point can see the object completely.

If we speak in 2D terms, we are trying to break down the mesh in star-shaped polyhedrons.

There is an algorithm on this by Keil for the 2 dimensions (Minimum star-shaped decomposition) but I haven't found anything on 3D.

There are,however, papers on convex decomposition and this works but it will lead into more parts than I would like .  Will I have to rely on these? How else should I approach this?

Extra notes: 
We have to do with polyhedrons with no holes and the decomposition doesn't have to be the minimum one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53142/decomposing-a-concave-mesh-into-a-set-of-convex-meshes

Comment: I'm not looking for convex decomposition. I just asked if that's my only alternative.

Comment: Try searching for approximate convex decomposition. That will give you the minimum parts

Comment: Can I see the paper that you mentioned

Comment: I don't have a specific one since I only considered this as an alternative but it  seems like a good one is the one by Mamou and Gorble https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221129055_A_simple_and_efficient_approach_for_3D_mesh_approximate_convex_decomposition . It seems to rely on other papers though and I didn't get much from reading it.

Comment: Let us continue this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development)

Comment: This is related to (but not quite) the Art Gallery Problem for 3D, and it's an area of ongoing research. The general problem is both hard to solve optimally and hard to approximate well, so it helps to narrow down your requirements. Do you have any constraints on the shapes of the polyhedra you expect as inputs? (Eg. can they have holes, how many and of what shapes; are their faces orthogonal to one another, is there any pattern to their reflex edges...) And do you need the minimum such decomposition, or can your application tolerate some excess guards/parts?

Comment: I updated the question. It seems that finding an approximate convex decomposition and finding the mesh triangles inside each approximate convex object I might get somewhere. I will have to find a good article on this though as the one I mentioned above in the comments didn't help much. Are you aware of anyone?